# Unresolved external symbol from a console application in visual studio

Tags: c++, googletest, unresolved-external, googlemock

I created a console application project(let's call it ProjectA) in visual studio, and another project which is the googletest project to test the ProjectA. Now I got unresolved external symbol problem when testing functions that have definition in cpp. (If I put everything in .h, there's no problem). How to make the content in the cpp visible to the googletest project? I notice ProjectA only creates a exe but no lib...

Many thanks!

Comment: Wanna create a minimal example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided code, I can give high level details.

Try to link your ProjectA to projectB So that when linker try to link it will find the proper definition.